# Why Roles not checking if userIsInRole?

Tags: javascript, meteor, roles

I'm using Meteor and alanning:roles for user roles in my project. I'm trying to check if logged user has an admin permission.
I've tried all the ways.
That check returns false.
I've made what is in README of alanning:roles, like this:

```js
//server/init.js

var users = [
      {name:"Normal User",email:"normal@ehnormal.com.br",roles:[]},
  {name:"Usuario Secreto",email:"mauriciord@me.com",roles:['view-secrets']},
  {name:"Usuario Gerenciador",email:"mauricioreattoduarte@gmail.com",roles:['manage-users']},
  {name:"Mauricio",email:"mauricio@thcm.com.br",roles:['admin']}
];

_.each(users, function (user) {
  var id;

  id = Accounts.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: "apple1",
    profile: { name: user.name }
  });

  if (user.roles.length > 0) {
    // Need _id of existing user record so this call must come
    // after `Accounts.createUser` or `Accounts.onCreate`
    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles, 'default-group');
    Meteor.users.update({_id: id}, {$set:{'emails.0.verified': true}});
    console.log("usuario criado");
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles, 'default-group');
    //Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles);
  }
});
```

Like said in README, too:

```js
//server/publish.js
Meteor.publish(null, function (){
 return Meteor.roles.find({})
});
```

But when i try to check User's permission in routes.js: see [here](https://github.com/mauriciord/thomasicamargo/blob/master/lib/routes.js) on my repository.

```js
// lib/routes.js
var logado = FlowRouter.group({
    name: 'logadoRoutes',
  // se não estiver logado vai para /login
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    console.log('logado grupo');
    if(!Meteor.userId()) {
      FlowRouter.go('login');
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }]
});    
var admin = logado.group({
  prefix: '/admin',
  name: 'adminRoutes',
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    var loggedInUser = Meteor.userId();
    console.log('verificando admin ...');
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['view-secrets', 'admin'], "default-group")) {
      return true;
      console.log('é admin -  rotas');
    }
    console.log('não é admin -  rotas');
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Acesso Negado");
  }]
});
```

Here is my repository: https://github.com/mauriciord/thomasicamargo
Packages: https://github.com/mauriciord/thomasicamargo/blob/master/.meteor/packages

```
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library
standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
erasaur:meteor-lodash
stolinski:stylus-multi
fortawesome:fontawesome
spiderable
fastclick
raix:handlebar-helpers
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
accounts-ui
accounts-password
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
zimme:active-route
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
meteortoys:allthings
datariot:ganalytics
check
twbs:bootstrap
less
arillo:flow-router-helpers
alanning:roles
```

**UPDATE:** I changed in layout with `isInRole` (it was `ifInRole`), and now it's working.
I was trying to verify the condition on routes.js just pressing 'Enter' on the URL of Navigation Bar. localhost:3000/admin, but when i go this route via anchor link, the condition work 100% haha. In condition i've made this:

```js
if (Roles.subscription.ready() && Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['admin'], 'default-group')) {
      return true;
      console.log('é admin -  rotas');
    }
```

I don't know why, i'm new on MeteorJS.

Comment: In your role check you're checking the group: `"default-        group"` (with spaces) instead of `"default-group"`.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Hey @challett , it was just in editor here. I've updated the code, now working, but i don't know why when i press 'Enter' on Navigation Bar - http://localhost:3000/admin, the condition don't work.

Comment: That is likely because of how you are handling the redirect.

Comment: Sorry @challett but i didn't understand where !

Comment: Try adding a check on `Meteor.isLoggingIn()` before you check the role of the user somehow.  I am not familiar with FlowRouter so I can't give you a concrete solution at this moment, but it's likely caused by meteor logging in the user when you go to the page through the URL

Comment: Not yet ... I verified that when i go to page through the URL (navigation bar), the condition `if (Roles.subscription.ready()){` don't work, so does not result the `Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['admin'], 'default-group')` because roles subscribe not loaded. If there was a way of load roles subscribe on `route.js`, i could try that condition. How can i load roles subscribe on `routes.js` ?